# When installing Xcode from mac AppStore, where is the DMG?

Tags: xcode, mac-app-store

With the new requirement to install Xcode from mac AppStore, i would like to locate the install package (.dmg) and archive it somewhere.

Use case 1 : got 100+ workstations, dont want(need) to download 100+ times.

Use case 2 : I archive, ship, and later End-of-life a product built with Xcode 4.1.1. A premium customer requires an urgent bug fix, I would like to temporarily install a few workstations with THAT Xcode.

tia.

btw, same goes for Lion, or whatever future feline Apple may release.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

in case you download Xcode from AppStore, Pablo is right.

However, in case you want the "good old" download of the .dmg file from Apple's website, you have to login at the [Apple Developer Download](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) website (previously called: ADC Program Assets). You will find various versions of Xcode under "Developer Tools".

Comment: hey maggix, thank you for that. When i went through the developer portal, IT forced me to go via AppStore. I much prefer the way you suggested.

Comment: Just one note, though. I downloaded the Xcode 4.1 for Lion .dmg from Connect, and it seems to me (but correct me if I'm wrong) that it still install the Install Xcode application to the Applications folder. It's just an easier way to get the redistributable package.

Comment: yes it does ... but i can work around that easily (much easier than working around NOT having the dmg at all. FYI , the method suggested by Pablo also worked.

Comment: Thanks maggix, never heard of the Connect site until now. Prefer the good old DMG over the App Store any day.

Answer (score 5):

It's usually under `Applications` folder. The program is called `Install XCode`. You can copy and use that in your 100+ workstations.

[Here's a question on `apple.stackexchange.com` where you will find a similar problem/answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10102/is-it-safe-to-remove-the-install-xcode-application-after-installation).

Comment: Thanks Pablo, a usual case of forgetting the last ditch attempt ( spotlight :) ). Found it, it's on its way to my SVN repo.

Comment: Xcode installation on SVN repo? Wouldn't it be easier to just go to purchased tab in AppStore on every Mac? :)

Comment: hell no ... if you factor that an AppStore install is flaky (3 times on a specific MBP). Further, there is no way to know what other assenine usage policies will be placed by Apple in the coming months/years, i like to implement my own and be totally autonomous.   Also i tend to be caustic with change management. My repo gets backed-up on S3 frequently ... i guess its a case of belts and suspenders, but I wont risk losing/misplacing any piece in the robot ... and i can script completely the 'restore workstation' from a branch, inclusive of the dev environment.

Answer (score 2):

Once you are logged into apple developer portal you can navigate to following link to view all development resources available for downloads as .dmg file, it includes XCODE 5 too.

https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action

Comment: I suggest this is the best answer so far to the question.

Comment: I disagree as the question was about the Mac App Store and this answer does not cover it.

Answer (score 0):

If you find the aforementioned Install Xcode package and ctrl-click on it, choose Show Package contents to reveal the .dmg file. It's in there somewhere.